# Cannot change brightness on Samsung rv411 laptop computer

Tags: linux, brightness

I am using a Samsung RV411 s03 laptop computer. I have tried several linux distribution on my laptop computer; I have got a problem with them which is the brightness of the monitor cannot be changed by any methods including using the Fn key and up or down arrow keys and changing the grub property. I finally think the problem is caused by the driver program which is not installed because I have tried that when I was installing the windows 7 but it has be solved when I installed the driver program. However there is no corresponding driver program for linux. Therefore I would like to ask for your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which distro you using now and I guess this is not the best place to ask for that.

But I do have a Samsung laptop too and guess the project sansung-tools can resolve this problem for you.

https://launchpad.net/samsung-tools
https://github.com/voria/samsung-tools

I hope it helps you.